# Irregular Outcome when using findObjectsInBackground

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uiimage

I am trying to implement code in order to retrieve group information from my `Parse` cloud.

The issue comes in displaying the user images. as sometimes (I think) the image is not found yet, but the simulator tries to download it.

The code is running as following:
in `viewDidLoad` I use `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`
in order to find the groupMember in class "Group" by their ids.

in `viewDidAppear` (which I figure is a bit behind in the timeline) `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` to find their profile Pictures. Storing them in an Array and downloading the images in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Is there a way to guarantee an outcome? Or even a better method to reach my goal?

Comment: I have a feeling the irregularity of the problem is because of the calls running in the background and not being complete before you are working on the cell.

Comment: Reason for asking is that the Parse PFQueryTableViewController provides a PFTableViewCell - and both these classes are very happy running in the background and working well together.

Now the important thing about PFTableViewCell is that if you wish to display an image in your table, then you can give it a standard image that is initially displayed to users and then in the background it can check to see if a real image exists and if it does, download and switch out the initial image.

http://blog.bizzi-body.com/2015/02/13/how-to-display-parse-com-images-in-a-table-view/

Comment: That was my call as well. Thanks Ian I will have a deep look at your url.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the irregularity of the problem is because of the calls running in the background and not being complete before you are working on the cell.

But....  are you using a Parse PFQueryTableViewController or a UITableView?

Reason for asking is that the Parse PFQueryTableViewController provides a PFTableViewCell - and both these classes are very happy running in the background and working well together.

Now the important thing about PFTableViewCell is that if you wish to display an image in your table, then you can give it a standard image that is initially displayed to users and then in the background it can check to see if a real image exists and if it does, download and switch out the initial image.

http://blog.bizzi-body.com/2015/02/13/how-to-display-parse-com-images-in-a-table-view/